# C++ GDI+ how to get and load image from resource?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019, gdi+

I'm trying to display a PNG image from my resource file using GDI+.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

...
auto CALLBACK BorderlessWindow::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept -> LRESULT {

    if (auto window_ptr = reinterpret_cast<BorderlessWindow*>(::GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA))) {
        auto& window = *window_ptr;

        switch (msg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
            HDC          hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT  ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
           
            Graphics    graphics(hdc);
            Image image(L"C:\\my_image.png");
            graphics.DrawImage(&image, 50, 50);
           
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ::DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

...
int CALLBACK WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {
   
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
   
    ...

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

The code above is working for the local file, I wanted to use the resource file that I added to my project. How can I do that?

Comment: [`Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hinstance_constwchar)) should work

Comment: Note that the bitmap name in this case should be: `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_YOUR_BITMAP_RESOURCE_ID)`

Comment: ...But the resource must be saved under the Bitmap cathegory. I am not sure if You can do that with a PNG (VS automatically saves those into their own cathegory, which this constructor cannot load). You can get around that with the [`Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap(IStream*, BOOL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-fromstream), but that may be a little too complicated.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes - `Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1));` this doesn't work with PNG. I tried with BMP and it works. I need it to work on PNG.

Comment: @Papilion Yep. You can either try to force the PNG to be labeled as a Bitmap in the resource (so that the constructor recognizes it, but I am not certain a PNG *can* be labeled Bitmap) or pull it up using the imaging component.

Comment: did you know of an alternative way to display a PNG image?

Comment: @Papilion As I said, You can load it through the Imaging Component. Do You have some basic knowledge of COM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR:  FindResource, LoadResource, and LockResource to get a pointer to the image bytes.  Then make an IStream from it.  The IStream can be used to initialize a Gdi+ Image or Bitmap object. (Gdiplus::Bitmap derives from Gdiplus::Image)

Stick a new line into your .rc file:

```
IDI_MY_IMAGE_FILE    PNG      "foo.png"
```

And make sure IDI_MY_IMAGE_FILE is defined as an integer in your resource.h header file.

```
#define IDI_MY_IMAGE_FILE               131
```

Then to load the image at runtime:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* pBmp = LoadImageFromResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MY_IMAGE_FILE), L"PNG");
```

Where `LoadImageFromResource` is a helper function that does all the heavy work of loading a PNG from your application resources.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* LoadImageFromResource(HMODULE hMod, const wchar_t* resid, const wchar_t* restype)
{
    IStream* pStream = nullptr;
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* pBmp = nullptr;
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = nullptr;

    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResourceW(hInst, resid, restype);     // get the handle to the resource
    if (hrsrc)
    {
        DWORD dwResourceSize = SizeofResource(hMod, hrsrc);
        if (dwResourceSize > 0)
        {
            HGLOBAL hGlobalResource = LoadResource(hMod, hrsrc); // load it
            if (hGlobalResource)
            {
                void* imagebytes = LockResource(hGlobalResource); // get a pointer to the file bytes

                // copy image bytes into a real hglobal memory handle
                hGlobal = ::GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwResourceSize);
                if (hGlobal)
                {
                    void* pBuffer = ::GlobalLock(hGlobal);
                    if (pBuffer)
                    {
                        memcpy(pBuffer, imagebytes, dwResourceSize);
                        HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, TRUE, &pStream);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            // pStream now owns the global handle and will invoke GlobalFree on release
                            hGlobal = nullptr;
                            pBmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(pStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (pStream)
    {
        pStream->Release();
        pStream = nullptr;
    }

    if (hGlobal)
    {
        GlobalFree(hGlobal);
        hGlobal = nullptr;
    }

    return pBmp;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work for png, bmp, jpg, gif, and most Tiff formats.

Comment: It should be noted that the *resource type name* `PNG`, which you specify in the .rc file, is totally arbitrary and has no special meaning in this context. It would only be relevant if you had gone through all resources with `EnumResourceTypesExW`.

Comment: Correct - it could have easily been named `FILE`, `BLOB`, or anything else.

Comment: GIF displayed but the animation is gone.

Comment: @Papilion Let me guess, you didn't write any animation code to select the active frame (`Image::SelectActiveFrame`) in a timer callback...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, you don't get animations for free. But as @dialer points out, you can easily add support by using SelectActiveFrame and a SetTimer call.  If you need a hint on how to do that, make another question.

Comment: I'm new to this but I'm gonna give it a try, if anything goes wrong then I'll open a new question.

Comment: @Papilion - and don't forget to accept this answer if you found it useful for your original question (rendering PNG from resource).